# CakePHP 2: Use error information in errorXXX.ctp view

Tags: cakephp, error-handling, cakephp-2.0

I am interested in showing information about error has been triggered when errorXXX.ctp view shows.

I realized $url variable is used by default, but I tried with $code but is not working:

```
<p class="error">
    <strong><?php echo __d('cake', 'Error ' . $code); ?>: </strong>
    <?php printf(
        __d('cake', 'The requested address %s was not found on this server.'),
        "<strong>'{$url}'</strong>");
        ?>
</p>
```

I would like take variables like $code, $description, $url, ...

Someone know how I could fix it??

Comment: ```<?php echo $this->here; ?>``` gives you current URL. You should give more info about your controller and action.

Comment: @trante What I show is my error400.ctp view, which is the view I am redirected whe an error is triggered. I dont know really which controller/action is which call this view. I think $name and $url variables come from that controller/action, but I dont know which is.

Comment: In that solution your redirected page will not have 404 type headers, it will have 200 type headers. I recommend using CakePHP bult-in exceptions: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html